# Is $\forall_x\forall_y\forall_z\Big(P(x,x)\wedge(P(x,z)\implies\big(P(x,y)\vee P(y,z)\big)\Big)\implies\exists_x\forall_y P(x,y)$ tautology?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, satisfiability

Is formula
$$
\forall_x\forall_y\forall_z\Big(P(x,x)\wedge(P(x,z)\implies\big(P(x,y)\vee P(y,z)\big)\Big)\implies\exists_x\forall_y P(x,y)
$$
a tautology?

What's method to check this? Do I need to try to construct model which would be counterexample and try to take some conclusions from it or is there some easier way?

Comment: a closing ')' is missing

Comment: Have you seen sequents calculus in 1st order logic ?

Comment: Yes, try to produce a counterexample ... if you find one then it's not a tautology, and if there isn't one, then presumably you'll figure out exactly why there isn't one, and will be able to translate that into a proof that it is a tautology.

Comment: @RomainB. No, I did not.

Comment: The easiest counter example is an empty universe.  But I guess those are tacitly excluded.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I am confronted with this kind of question, I will first scan the statement and see if I can quickly make sense of it being a tautology (so in this case: if the consequent does indeed logically follows from its antecedent).

If I don't find a quick justification for that, I'll try to produce a counterexample ... if I find one then it's not a tautology, and if there isn't one, then presumably I can see why I wasn't able to find one, and hopefully will be able to translate that into a proof that it is a tautology after all.

Also, my search for counterexamples (especially when binary predicates are involved) typically goes something like this:

First, I go through a list of the 'usual suspects': for the domain I consider the  natural numbers, integers, or real numbers, and for the binary predicate I'll try things like $=$,  $<$, or $\le$.

If that doesn't quickly work, I'll move on to very simple but completely abstract domains, where there are $1$, $2$, or $3$ objects $a$, $b$, and $c$, and just play around with those.

If I don't get a quick answer there either, I'll try some more systematic method, like truth trees.

Fortunately for you, in this case the first method for finding a counterexample works just fine ... (yes, that's a big HINT)

Answer (score 1):

Let's re-write the formula :
$$\forall_x\forall_y\forall_z\Big(P(x,x)\wedge(P(x,z)\implies\big(P(x,y)\vee P(y,z)\big)\Big)\implies\exists_x\forall_y P(x,y)$$
$$\leftrightarrow \text{Because}  \ (A \implies B) \equiv (\lnot A \lor B)$$
$$\forall_x\forall_y\forall_z\Big(P(x,x)\wedge( \lnot P(x,z)\lor\big(P(x,y)\vee P(y,z)\big)\Big)\implies\exists_x\forall_y P(x,y)$$
$$\leftrightarrow \text{Using the distributivity}$$ 
$$\forall_x\forall_y\forall_z\Big(\big(P(x,x)\wedge \lnot P(x,z)\big)\lor\big((P(x,x)\wedge P(x,y)\big)\lor\big((P(x,x)\wedge P(y,z)\big)\Big)\implies\exists_x\forall_y P(x,y)$$
$$\leftrightarrow \text{Using} \ (A \implies B) \equiv (\lnot A \lor B)$$ 
$$ \lnot\Bigg(\forall_x\forall_y\forall_z\Big(\big(P(x,x)\wedge \lnot P(x,z)\big)\lor\big((P(x,x)\wedge P(x,y)\big)\lor\big((P(x,x)\wedge P(y,z)\big)\Big)\Bigg)\lor\exists_x\forall_y P(x,y)$$
$$\leftrightarrow \text{Using de Morgan on $\lnot\forall_{x,y,z}$}$$ 
$$ \Bigg(\exists_x\exists_y\exists_z\lnot\Big(\big(P(x,x)\wedge \lnot P(x,z)\big)\lor\big((P(x,x)\wedge P(x,y)\big)\lor\big((P(x,x)\wedge P(y,z)\big)\Big)\Bigg)\lor\exists_x\forall_y P(x,y)$$
$$\leftrightarrow \text{Using $\lnot( A \lor B) \equiv (\lnot A \land \lnot B) $}$$ 
$$ \Bigg(\exists_x\exists_y\exists_z\Big(\lnot\big(P(x,x)\wedge \lnot P(x,z)\big)\land\lnot\big((P(x,x)\wedge P(x,y)\big)\land\lnot\big((P(x,x)\wedge P(y,z)\big)\Big)\Bigg)\lor\exists_x\forall_y P(x,y)$$
$$\leftrightarrow \text{Using $\lnot( A \land B) \equiv (\lnot A \lor \lnot B) $}$$ 
$$ \Bigg(\exists_x\exists_y\exists_z\Big(\big(\lnot P(x,x)\lor P(x,z)\big)\land\big((\lnot P(x,x)\lor \lnot P(x,y)\big)\land\big((\lnot P(x,x)\lor \lnot P(y,z)\big)\Big)\Bigg)\lor\exists_x\forall_y P(x,y)$$
$$\leftrightarrow \text{Using $(\exists_x A) \lor (\exists_x B) \equiv \exists_x (A \lor B)$}$$ 
$$ \exists_x\exists_y\exists_z\Bigg(\Big(\big(\lnot P(x,x)\lor P(x,z)\big)\land\big((\lnot P(x,x)\lor \lnot P(x,y)\big)\land\big((\lnot P(x,x)\lor \lnot P(y,z)\big)\Big)\lor \big(\forall_y P(x,y)\big)\Bigg)$$

If you want to prove a tautology here you just need to prove that $\big(\forall_y P(x,y)\big)$ is *true* for a fixed *x*.